# jquery animate stops working but css works

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, dom-manipulation

I have a div on a page that I'm fading in and out a loading gif while I replace the content.  When I replace the DOM element, the new DOM elements are no longer affected by jquery's .animate method, but the .css method will still affect the elements.  Anybody have any idea what might cause this?

Code:

```
var container = $('#container');
var oldContent = container.find('.Content');

oldContent.find('.LoadingPanel').css('display', '').animate({ opacity: 0.8 });

_ajaxHandler.requestNewData(function(content) {

    var newContent = content.find('.Content');

    newContent.find('.LoadingPanel').css({
        display: '',
        opacity: 0.8
    });


    // Replace in the array and in the DOM
    oldContent.replaceWith(newContent);

    // This does not work
    // newContent.find('.LoadingPanel').animate({ opacity: 0 });

    // This does
    newContent.find('.LoadingPanel').css({ opacity: 0 });
});
```

Markup:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='Content'>
        <div class='LoadingPanel'>
            <img src='loading.gif' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly post a fiddle. Your JS code is incomplete...

Comment: I'll try to get a fiddle up that reproduces the error, but I'm not sure how to replicate the requestNewData function in a fiddle.  It actually makes a call to the server and content is the document object of that call.

Comment: whats this display: '' about?

Comment: what's `container` and `content` (the things you are doing a `.find('.Content')` on

Comment: @Alex when working as I would like, after I animate the opacity to 0 I will set the display to none so that I can interact with the elements behind the loading panel.  This is the counter to that.

Comment: @Pete This is updated in the code.

Comment: that still doesn't explain what `content` is - the thing you are loading `newContent` from

Comment: @Pete Oh sorry, I thought you meant the other content object.  The inner content object is the $('#content') object that is returned when the $.ajax call returns from the server.